# how to import script file in HTML in node.js project

Tags: node.js

I'm new member in this field & this is my first question on stackoverflow..

I trying to make QR code scanner web application on Node.js, and I using "qr-scanner" dependency for this.

but when I run this application an error comes in console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

because Failed to load file, so I edit the path in HTML file in script section but still I am facing same issue..

So I am requesting to you please give me suggestion for correction..

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 2 methods:

**import** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import { export1 } from "module-name";
```

**require** (https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp)

```
var http = require('http');
```